# How do I access JSON objects that has array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access review_text in the following JSON, but it shows me this:

```
Object {returnObj: Object}
    returnObj: Object
        item_1: "4"
        reviews: Array[4]
            0: Object
                review_text:
```

My approach is this:

```
returnObj.reviews[i].reviewer_name
```

But am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Where am I going wrong??

Comment: Try posting more code, this is the correct way to access that property.  The error means whatever `returnOjb` is doesn't have a prop called `reviews`

Comment: Could you paste your original JSON response?

Comment: The error means that property `reviews` doesn't exist in `returnObj`.

Comment: this is the original JSON response

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you posted. The error must be somewhere else or is context dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I tried, it works ...

```
var returnObj = {
    item_1: 'item_1',
    reviews: [
        {review_text: 'this you wanted?'},
        {review_text: 'this you wanted?'},
        {review_text: 'this you wanted?'},
        {review_text: 'this you wanted?'}
    ]
}
window.alert(returnObj.reviews[0].review_text);
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/p7oc5ndy/)